# Create multiple objects of module pattern

Tags: javascript

Please look at the sample code below:

```
var sample = (function () {
  var a, b;
  var sample = function (x, y) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
  };
  return {
    add: function () {
      return a + b;
    }
  }
})();
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

How can I create multiple objects of the sample object?

How should I write constructors?

I tried creating object by:

```
var s = new sample(1, 2);
```

But, it throws an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modular pattern provides a singleton object only. So, you can't create instances of it.

However, there is a workaround. A slight change in the above code can enable you to create objects.

```
var sample = function (x, y) {
  var a = x; 
  var b = y;

  return {
    add: function () {
      return a + b;
    }
  }
};
```

now, I can call

```
var nine = new sample(4, 5); 
var five = new sample(2, 3);
alert(nine.add());
alert(five.add());
```